# Generic Constructors in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and to practice I'm trying to create a library for generic playing cards (it should be possible to implement different types of cards).

To do this I created a `Card` trait, which defines a constructor:

```
pub trait Card {
    fn from_id(id: u8) -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;
}
```

I have a Deck that can initialize itself by creating all it's cards:

```
impl<C> Deck<C>
where
    C: Card,
{
    fn new(size: u32, constructor: fn(u8) -> C) -> Deck<C> {
        let cards: Vec<C> = (0..size).map(|i| constructor(i as u8)).collect();
        Deck { cards }
    }
```

Then for `TestCard` which implements `Card` I can construct a `Deck` like so:

```
    struct TestCard {
        id: u8,
    }

    impl Card for TestCard {
        fn from_id(id: u8) -> TestCard {
            TestCard { id }
        }
    }

    let deck = Deck::new(3, TestCard::from_id);
```

I currently pass the constructor directly, i.e. `TestCard::from_id`, BUT we know `TestCard` must have a `from_id` method as it implements the `Card` trait. Is there a way I can just pass the type of card I want the `Deck` to have, e.g. `TestCard` or some equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way I can just pass the type of card I want the Deck to have, e.g. TestCard or some equivalent?

It's already there, it's `C`. So you can just use `C::from_id`.

```rust
impl<C: Card> Deck<C> {
    fn new(size: u8) -> Deck<C> {
        let cards = (0..size).map(C::from_id).collect();
        Deck { cards }
    }
}
```

Incidentally I've no idea why you added a `where Self: Sized` in your trait definition, it doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Thanks, I think was previously trying to pass 'Card' directly via the method and the Rust compiler was complaining with something like:
"... because associated function has no `self` parameter". The addition of `Sized` fixed those errors but that was the wrong approach, so yes is now unnecessary.

Comment: Yes that wouldn't work, if the parameter's type was `Card` it would be a "bare" trait object, which is unsized as any struct can theoretically implement the trait, and thus be passed as a card. Thus trait objects are normally behind a pointer e.g. `Box<dyn Card>`.